# How to use default HTML DOM functions with D3js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, d3.js, bootstrap-modal

I have been trying to find out how to clear an HTML form in a Bootstrap modal I made, and I primarily use D3js for object manipulation. However, as I have been trying to reset the values of the form using D3 (such as `d3.select('#my-text-input').attr('value', '')` or `d3.select('#my-text-input').attr('value', null)`), the values still remain. I found that there is the `.reset()` function that comes default in HTML, but every time I try to use some variation of `d3.select('#my-form').reset()` I get an error saying that this is not a D3 function.

This leads me to my bigger question: is there a way to use the built-in HTML methods with a D3 selection?

*As a side note, I discovered **an** answer to my own question, which I have posted in case some poor soul has the same problem as me. However, I am very open to other tips, comments, or suggestions that fall in this general topic.*

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, it looks like there is a work around.
If you add `.node()` after your D3 selection, you can use HTML built-in methods. For example, this was how I was able to use `.reset()` in my own code:

```js
d3.select('#my-form').node().reset()
```

or also:

```js
let form = d3.select('#my-form').node()  
form.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', (e) => {
  form.reset()
}
```

`'hidden.bs.modal'` is an [event listener added by Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#events). There is not a lot of info in the Github docs on `selection.node()` from D3, but there is [a little snippet on the *d3-selection* repository](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_node).

Any other pointers are welcome. I am always trying to be a better developer. I just thought this might help someone else out there.